# Why useEffect is passing two times?

Tags: react-native, hook, use-effect

Im trying to useEffect without success.. This is my code...

```
const [listVisaoGeral, setListVisaoGeral] = useState([]);
    
    first useEffect:  
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(First)
        async function getVisaoGeral() {
          try {
            await axiosInstance
              .get("....")
              .then(function (responseVisaoGeral) {
                return responseVisaoGeral.data;
              })
              .then(function (treatedVisaoGeralList) {
                setListVisaoGeral(treatedVisaoGeralList);
              });
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            Alert.alert(
              "Erro",
              "Não foi possível consultar a lista de recursos. Por favor, tente novamente."
            );
          }
        }
    
        getVisaoGeral();
      }, []);
    
    
    second use effect : 
    
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(Second)
        
      }, [listVisaoGeral]);
```

I don't understand why it's passing two times in the second useEffect since I change state only once...

Comment: `I don't understand why it's passing two times in the second useEffect since I change state only once...` It obviously has to run _before_ the change aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is run two times as expected.

1st time because all `useEffects` are invoked after the first render, irrespective of changes in dependencies.

2nd time because state's changed.

If you don't want to run what's inside your useEffect during first render, you can use some kind of flag using `useRef` to identify the first render and return early.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const isFirstRender = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isFirstRender.current) {
    isFirstRender.current = false;
    return;
  }

  console.log('Second');
}, [listVisaoGeral]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, you mean that even if I pass a state inside [ ]  of useEffect like I did it will trigger it in the first render anyway? I tought only blank [ ] would pass in the first render...

Comment: Yes, even if you pass a state inside [ ] useEffect will trigger in the first render.